# How to redirect Subdomain to domain with same url in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have installed a gem rails_admin in my application now i want to redirect this url **eritheia-labs.localhost:3000/admin/dashboard** to *localhost:3000/admin/dashboard*

i wanna access rails admin via **localhost:3000/admin** instead of **eritheia-labs.localhost:3000/admin**   or if enter this url it will redirect me to localhost:3000/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following to your config/routes.rb

```
constraints(host: "eritheia-labs.localhost") do
  match '/admin/(*path)' => redirect { |params, req|
    "http://localhost:3000#{req.fullpath}"
  }, via: [:get, :head]
end
```

and make sure it is before the `mount RailsAdmin::Engine` line.

This code should redirect any requests for 'http://eritheia-labs.localhost:3000/admin/*path' to 'http://localhost:3000/admin/*path'.

Comment: Working perfect thanks Cameron you are amazing

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is....
in **routes.rb** file

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.role == "admin" } do
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
end
```

Put this Code Under  **constraints DomainConstraint do**
this will access the rails_admin with localhost:3000/admin only, not with example.localhost:3000/admin